# Run- time error 1004 - Method 'Name' of object Worksheer failed

Tags: excel, vba

Run- time eroor 1004 massege is merged, thouth the code works just fine. Moreover, the code might runs  too slowly so that it takes 30 seconed to enter to the "SummaryProject.xlsm"

The code takes all the xlsm files like  the "SummaryProject.xlsm"'s directory. Copies each row from "Drill"
Sheets and paste them into "Summary" sheet in the "SummaryProject.xlsm". 
In addition This summary xlsm is refreshed each time you open it by the current attending files.

```
Sub Import_to_Master()

Dim sFolder As String
Dim sFile As String
Dim wbD As Workbook
Dim wbS As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wbS = ThisWorkbook
    sFolder = wbS.Path & "\"

    sFile = Dir(sFolder)
    Do While sFile <> " "

        If sFile <> wbS.Name Then
        Set wbD = Workbooks.Open(sFolder & sFile)
        'open the file; add condition to

        'Adapt this part
        wbD.Sheets("Drill").Range("A2:P2").Copy
        wbS.Activate

        Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 
        0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        wbD.Worksheets("Log").Copy before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

        Set ws = Sheets("Log")
        With ws
        .Name = Range("D1").Value
        End With

        wbD.Activate
        wbD.Close savechanges:=True  'close without saving
        End If
        sFile = Dir   'next file
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Your range isn't qualified, so Excel probably isn't using the D1 value you're hoping for. Try: `.Name = Sheets("name of the sheet").Range("D1").Value`

Comment: `.Name = .Range("D1").Value` put a dot before Range

Comment: Only put the dot before `Range` IF the `D1` you're interested in is on the sheet called `Log`.